In react native android release apk getting webview issue Error Code:-2 Description:net::ERR_NAME_NOT_RESOLVED
Error loading page
Domain:undefined
Error Code:-2
Description:net::ERR_NAME_NOT_RESOLVED
Getting this issue in release apk in android react native
I already used    android:usesCleartextTraffic="true" in menifest file

In release apk may be android is unable to find the path of your html file.
